# Android application does not show alertBox for enabling gps

Tags: android, location

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.i(TAG, "INSIDE onCreate");

    //ACCESSING LOCATION MANAGER


    String svcName=Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationmanager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(svcName);


    //SPECIFY THE CRITERIA

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);


    //get the list of providers



    provider=locationmanager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

     if(provider==null)
     {
         Log.i(TAG, "inside enable gps");
         final boolean enablegps = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         //show dialog box and enable gps..
         if(!enablegps)
         {

             Log.i(TAG, "dialog box");

final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Wmi2Activity.this);


        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Is GPS Enable??");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                         .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                         .setCancelable(false)
                          .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,final int id) {

                                             //gotoEnablrGPS();
                     dialog.cancel();

                }
              });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,final int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
}


                }
         else{
         mylocation.setText("no location provider available");
         }

     }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception? Have you added gps permissions?

Comment: Holy wall of code, Batman! What's your question, exactly?

Comment: instead of AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
write only alertDialogBuilder.create();

Comment: are you sure `provider=locationmanager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);` is returning you the GPS provider and not something else. It might be that the GPS is on but you are recieving some other provider from that method

Comment: @udiboy thaqt provider returns null when gps is not on and goes into if(!enablegps) but it does not shows dialog box it shows TAG inside if conditon but does not show alertbox

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Wmi2Activity.this);
```

to:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

to this code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder().setTitle("Is GPS Enable??")       
                     .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                     .setCancelable(false)
                      .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,final int id) {

                                         //gotoEnablrGPS();
                 dialog.cancel();

            }
          }).setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,final int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

It might work.